# how to center css class images with text?

Tags: html, css, image, text, block

What I got:
http://jsfiddle.net/nCs88/

What I'm trying to get:
http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/888/42576e33afe343a0bab6a40.png

I'm an absolute beginner, I'm trying to get the button images to center with the text. Eternally grateful for any help its been frustrating me for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply `vertical-align:middle` to both classes.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nCs88/1/)**

Add:

```
.dbutton, .ctrlbutton {
    vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<style type="text/css">
 .itButton{
    border:1px solid #abc; 
    display:table-cell; 
    text-align:center;        
    /* width:200px */  
  }    
 .itBtn{
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  }
</style>
```

and

```
<div class="itButton">
   <div class="itBtn"><img src="user.png" alt="" /></div>
   <div class="itBtn">My Button</div>
</div>
```